# Flex 4.6 - Detecting screen dimensions for mobile - systemManager.screen.width vs Stage.width

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flex4, flash-builder, flex4.5

For mobile Flex / Flash Builder, is it better to detect screen dimensions using `systemManager.screen.*` or `Stage.*` - and why?

Answer (score 5):

In most cases, it is more reliable to use `FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.width` and `FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.height`.

Answer (score 2):

When building apps, I think it is more important to know the space I have to work with than it is to know the actual screen dimensions.

To get this information, I would tie into the Flex Framework and use the unscaledWidth and unscaledHeight properties passed into the updateDisplayList() method.

The question is, why do you need to detect screen dimensions.  If you just need to use them to size and position a component's children, then I believe the solution I describe above is the best one. If you need this information for some other reason, explain.

---

This is one way to size and position a label inside the updateDisplayList of it's container:

```
protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void{
 super.updateDisplayList(unscaledwidth, unscaledHeight);
 // first position it
 // you could also use this.myLabel.move(x,y) method to position the element
 this.myLabel.x = 0;
 this.myLabel.y = 0;

 // then size it
 // sizing to 100% height/width of container
 this.myLabel.height = unscaledHeight;
 this.myLabel.width = unscaledWidth;

 // or you could also use setActualSize; which is slightly different than setting height and width
 // becaues using setActualSize won't set the explicitHeight/explicitWidth, therefore measure will still 
 // execute
 this.myLabel.setActualSize(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight)

 // or you could set the label to it's measured height and measured width
 this.myLabel.height = this.myLabel.getExplicitOrMeasuredHeight();
 this.myLabel.width = this.myLabel.getExplicitOrMeasuredWidth();

}
```

Comment: I am still not clear how `updateDisplayList()` can be used to position a component's children. For multiline text (default) `labels`, a `width` has to be set. Following various tutorials online, I set this width from the stage/screen width - 2*margin (assuming it spans the readable width of the screen). How would updateDisplayList work there?

Comment: I updated my answer to provide some sample code on how to size a component inside updateDisplayList.

Comment: I guess what I'm still not understanding is how do you size the container at runtime? It seems that's what would vary across screen sizes.

Comment: The Flex framework figures that out and passes it into updateDisplayList as function parameters.

Comment: Still not clear how Flex is setting/getting the container width. Say I design a multiline label that fits a smartphone's narrow screen. The container constraint for width is 300px (~80% of screen width), would Flex know how to scale this to 800px on a 1000px tablet screen width?

Comment: A component can never size itself; so you can't design a component to size itself to 80% of the screen.  The parent is always responsible for positioning and sizing it's children.  If you want to know how Flex determines sizes, you'll have to start digging into framework code.  I'd start by reviewing the LayoutManager and the Application classes.